# loop through jTextField and save in ArrayList

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I'm trying to loop through the jTextFields on my form. Not sure if this is the best way or not. Also, for some reason instead of starting at jTextField1 it's starting at jTextField2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6.. 
This is what I have so far..

```
private void getTextField(Container container)
{
    for (Component c : container.getComponents()){
        if (c instanceof JTextField){
            JTextField f = (JTextField)c;
            f.getText();
            arl.add(f.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your textfields into a `List` or array when you create them.  The order is not defined by the variable name of the component, but the order in which they are added to the container and other factors

Comment: I did created an ArrayList like this private ArrayList<String> arl = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, create a `List` of `JTextField`'s, when you create your text fields, put them into that list

Comment: And is this still an efficient way of looping through the textFields? I did notice that it also loops through everything in the form. Does this slow down the program at all or is there a better way?

Comment: The jTextFields were created in netbeans. Maybe a better way would of been to created everything manually?

Comment: I don't know about "efficient", but it's easier to less error prone. What happens when your text fields live in other containers?

Comment: You can add the text fields post creation (after `initComponents` for example)

Comment: Not really too sure I understand how to do this.. Could you clarify? I'm new to Java programming.